# Oracle query not executing in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a query :

```
update (select tmp."table1" as tmpid, 
               del."table1" as  delid 
          from "table1_TMP" tmp ,
               "table1_DEL" del 
         where del."table2" = tmp."table2" and 
               del."REFSEQNO" = tmp."REFSEQNO")
   set tmpid = delid;
```

This query runs in oracle without any problem.

How can I modify this query to run on Postgresql?

Comment: +1 because I did not know Oracle has updateable inline views. That is cool.

Comment: Yeah, that's really impressive, especially on a join view.

Comment: Very efficient too, but limited to views where there are sufficient constraints in place to guarantee that each row in the update target cannot join to multiple rows. There was, and maybe still is, an undocumented optimiser hint BYPASS_UJVC to prevent the checking prior to execution, but it didn't work in at least one version and recently MERGE is preferred where the constraints are not in place. Oracle will also DELETE on a join view -- the child rows are deleted, which makes sense of course.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would do it.

```
update "table1_TMP" tmp
set "table1" = del."table1"
from "table1_DEL" del
where del."table2" = tmp."table2" and
      del."REFSEQNO" = tmp."REFSEQNO"
```

Comment: Yup. They key is that postgresql allows a `from` clause in an update statement.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html